# Local outdoor positioning system

Tags: gps

I am trying to create a local positioning system with a accuracy of less than half a meter. I live in an area with poor cellular coverage(none) and I am in need of a system which would be able to track an object moving around near my house/surrounding area, this object could be a animal such as a cat or dog. I have looked at RTK, but they are too expensive, INS have to much drift over a long period. The garden around my house has trees bushes and a old barn which will stop line of sight solutions.

I want to be able to use an arduino or raspberry pi, and I want to keep the project under £100. If there are any systems that might work please respond.

Many thanks

Comment: Please See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it currently stands your question is considered off topic

Comment: What should I change in my question? sorry, I am new to this :/

Comment: @Noobdog178 Stackoverflow is specifically for programming related questions. Specifically troubleshooting/debugging code. Have a look a how to post a minimal complete verifiable  example. It will be in the drop down for the help section. Asking for suggestions on Stackoverflow will likely illicit debate or attract poor answers. Therefore a question detailing what you have tried so far, or what research you have done is required for any meaningful answer. Good luck

Comment: But just to point you in the right direction google "spi gps module" and "esp8266 long range"